# Errors adding multiple Subtitles with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video, mp4, subtitles

I am trying to soft-encode 3 subtitle files into my film.
I extracted the subtitles from the DVD using ByteCopy

I am using this command to add the files:

```
ffmpeg -i BloodDiamond.mp4 -i BLOODDIAMOND_1_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_6_English.srt -i BLOODDIAMOND_8_English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -map 2 -map 3 -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=eng -metadata:s:s:1 language=eng -metadata:s:s:2 language=eng BloodDiamond_Subs.mp4
```

But I get this kind of errors in the output:

> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value
> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40]
> Application provided duration: -103001 / timestamp: 3405107000 is out of range for mov/mp4 format [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value
>
> [mp4 @ 000001bdadf19c40] Application provided duration: -857000 / timestamp: 3476787000 is out of range for mov/mp4 format [mp4 @000001bdadf19c40] pts has no value

is there something I am missing here?